# How to change value of datagridview based on cell value

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access

i am fetching data from access table in datagridview. Access table have one lookup column.
so when i fetch table in datagridview it is showing the value in numbers.

i want to get lookup value in datagridview not numbers.

should i use some conditional formatting for is there any other way to do that.

Comment: nothing i am not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Do not use lookup fields in table design. They only create the kind of problems that you are running into. Use a SQL statement or query as your datasource.

```
Select T1.*, T2.DescriptionField FROM Table1 AS T1 INNER JOIN 
TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.LookupField = T2.LookupField
```